# Upgraded to Windows 10, can't find hyper-v management tools

Tags: windows, hyper-v, windows-10-preview

I do a search for "hyper-v" in the search box and don't see it.  I also searched for it inside the control panel and it's not there.  In the turn on windows features in the control panel, I see that everything hyper-v is still checked.

Answer (score 15):

The Hyper-V management tools are now a Microsoft Management Console snap-in. Run `mmc` and choose "Add/Remove Snap-in" from the File menu. Select the Hyper-V manager and press the `Add >` button in the middle to enable it. (If you get a dialog asking for extra configuration info, fill it out and hit OK.) Click OK to close the Add/Remove Snap-in dialog. The selected tools snap into the MMC instance.

From there, you can expand its "folders" in the left pane and click an entry to modify/configure it in the main window.

Comment: You should be able to then save it so you can open it from your saved file later.

Comment: You can also open it via Control Panel/Administrative Tools. There's a Hyper-V Manager shortcut that would save you a couple of clicks in Management Console.

Comment: There is no Hyper-V manager there, virtualization is enabled in BIOS.

Comment: @TiagoRedaelli Is Hyper-V enabled in Windows Features?

Comment: I´m Using Windows Home, so it does not exist apparently and I would need to upgrade to Pro or Student.

Comment: @RaYell comment is best, use Control Panel and you can make shortcut/pin app etc.